# Make clickable link in menu with kotlin

Tags: java, android, mobile, kotlin, navigation

I try to make a Bottom navigation, I have this code

```
val bottomNavigation = findViewById<View>(R.id.bottom_navigation) as 
  BottomNavigationView
    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.botom__nav__home ->
                // Action when tab 1 selected
                val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
            R.id.botom__nav__profile ->
                // Action when tab 2 selected
                val intent = Intent(this, LikeActivity::class.java)
            else ->
                // Action when tab 3 selected
                val intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
        }
        true
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, 99)
}
```

I have these errors:

```
' Expecting an expression '
' Expecting "->" '
```

For each element in the " When " ...

Can somebody help me to fix these errors?

Comment: See donfuxx's answer below. Or enclose each element after -> in curly braces {val intent....}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declare `val intent` various times inside the when block. To solve this just move the declaration of the intent outside of your when block, for example like this:

```
lateinit var intent:Intent
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {

        R.id.botom__nav__home ->
            // Action when tab 1 selected
            intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        R.id.botom__nav__profile ->
            // Action when tab 2 selected
            intent = Intent(this, LikeActivity::class.java)
        else ->
            // Action when tab 3 selected
            intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
    }
    true
}
startActivityForResult(intent, 99)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `item ->` in this line

```
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {`
```